# Guardar elementos de varios inputs

Tags: javascript, dom, entrada, local-storage

Estoy haciendo una app para guardar/ordenar información en pequeñas cantidades, ya llevo adelantado la mayoría del proyecto, pero aun no logro poder guardar la información que tengo en todos los inputs que se crean, para posteriormente acceder a ellos y tenerlos en la misma posicion.

```js
var caja = document.getElementById("caja");
var boton = document.getElementById("btn");
var borrar = document.getElementById("btn2");
var guardar = document.getElementById("btn3");
var obtener = document.getElementById("btn4");

function crearinput(){
 
 var salto = document.createElement("br");

 var x = document.createElement("input");
 x.type = "button";

 
 var select = document.createElement( 'select' );

 //Opción A
 var optionA = document.createElement( 'option' );
 optionA.value = 'optA'; //Valor que te llegará en el formulario
 optionA.textContent = 'Opción A'; // Texto visible.
 select.appendChild(optionA);
 
 var optionB = document.createElement( 'option' );
 optionB.value = 'optB';
 optionB.textContent = 'Opción B';
 select.appendChild(optionB);
 

 var input = document.createElement("input");
 input.type = "text";
 input.setAttribute("id", "input");
 
 caja.appendChild(x);
 caja.appendChild(select);
 caja.appendChild(input); 
 caja.appendChild(salto);
 
 
 
 x.onclick = function(){
  caja.removeChild(select);
  caja.removeChild(input);
  caja.removeChild(x);
  caja.removeChild(salto);
 
 }
 
 obtener.onclick = function(){
  var archivitos = localStorage.getItem("info");
  document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML = archivitos
 }
 
 guardar.onclick = function(){
  var archivo = document.getElementById("input").value
  localStorage.setItem("info", archivo);

  document.getElementById("input").value = "";

 }


}


function borrar(){
 var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
 checkbox.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
 caja.appendChild(checkbox)
}






boton.addEventListener("click", crearinput);
borrar.addEventListener("click", borrar);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css">
<html>
<head>
 <title>Web</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
   <div id="caja"></div>
   <input type="button" name="" id="btn" value="Agregar Valor">
   <input type="button" name="" id="btn2" value="Remover Valor">
   <input type="button" name="" id="btn3" value="Guardar" >
   <input type="button" name="" id="btn4" value="Obtener" >

   <p id="pp"></p>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="web.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Jonathan. No está muy claro lo que pides. Puedes explicar mejor que necesitas?  Añade ejemplos de lo que introduces, lo que extraes y como lo requires. mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Las etiquetas `meta` y `link` deben ir dentro del `head`. `localStorage` pisará la información previa de un item añadido si se añade otro con el mismo nombre, por lo que puedes asignar un item para cada caso o serializar un objeto e ir añadiendo y quitando según te convenga. [Usando la API de almacenamiento web](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/API_de_almacenamiento_web/Usando_la_API_de_almacenamiento_web)

Answer (score 0):

veras para acceder a la info de tu codigo utilizaria este codigo:

```
// devuelve el dom con id caja
var caja = document.getElementById("caja"); 
// devuelve todos los inputs de tipo texto
var inputs = caja.querySelector('input[type=text]');
inputs.forEach(function(input){
   // realizaria las acciones ...
})
```

Luego deberias trabajar con los tios input, getValue y toda lo demas. En principio esto te lo devolveria ordenado.

Para guardar objectos JavaScript en el localStorage hay serializar y deserializarlos de JSON.

para guardar un dato en el localStorage debes utilizar estos comandos, imaginate que tengo un objecto data con una array inputs:

```
var data = { 
  inputs: [
           {id:0,posicion: 1, opcion: "A", valor: "X"},
           {id:0,posicion: 1, opcion: "A", valor: "X"}
        ]
};

localStorage.set("items",JSON.stringify(data)); //aquí se guardan los datos serializados
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.get("items"));
console.log(items.inputs); //aquí estarian tus inputs
```

Como ultimo consejo, el localStorage desaparece cuando se cierra el navegado, en vez de eso usa sessionStorage, se usa igual solo cambia el llamado.

Saludos!!

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias por ayuda pero tengo otro problema, ya pude guardar y acceder a los elementos del local storage, pero solo puedo guardar y acceder a la información del primer input, no la del resto, me podrías ayudar en eso? solo necesito poder guardar y acceder a la información de todos los inputs que estén en pantalla

Comment: Te lo pongo arriba

Comment: gracias por la ayuda lo intentare.

pd: corrígeme si estoy mal, pero estoy casi seguro que el local storage no se borra por mas que se cierre o reinicie el navegador, el session storage es por sesiones

Comment: Creo que en un navegador es correcto, el problema es que es accesible por otras aplicaciones. Mi consejo es que uses sessionStorage y nunca guardes datos relevantes en estos almacenamientos, si utilizas implementaciones tipo cordova si matas la aplicación el localStorage se pierde